# Is there any typescript definition file for ng-i18next?

Tags: i18next

I'm looking for a typescript definition file for the abstractions that are defined within the library ng-i18next (i18next for angularjs).

Looking through [the project's page](https://github.com/i18next/ng-i18next) I didn't find anything. And when I go to issues -> ask, I landed here at SO.

I can't find it there neither using `npm install ng-i18next` plus exploring the file system with the downloaded files.

So basically no luck disregarding the "interface" used for searching a typescript definition file. Perhaps it doesn't exists.

1. Via web-gui

[image]

2. Via local-cli
   [image]

Any data about the whereabout of this file will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

##### Answer: https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/ng-i18next/index.d.ts

Research: The repository https://github.com/i18next/ng-i18next has a link for typings, and it redirects to https://www.npmjs.com/package/typings, a deprecated repository that used to store typings, and it says in it's readme.md the following message:

`Starting from TypeScript 2.0, users can install typings using npm install @types/<package>. These typings are coming from DefinitelyTyped.`

So, in that repository (https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped) if you look for ng-i18next, it appears, nevertheless, its interface is just has  options: any, so it doesn't give you any help.

Comment: Good discovering and thanks for the insight! I haven't thought on going that way. Although I look at the definitions and several are missing... I mean, there is is an angularjs filter, a directive, all of these are object with brand new properties to be typed... but well, I guess that probably that is the most complete type definition file going around in the web; the proyect itself seems to be quite abandoned (as angularjs is actually deprecated it may has sense). Perhaps.. this is my time to tipify and make some contribution.